# Dafny assertion passes but lemma fails

Tags: dafny

For some reason dafny reports that the ensure condition for PreorderTraversalChildrenAreLater might not always hold even though the quantified expression always holds... later on in the same lemma. Ideally, once I've shown the existence k, I was attempting to show that all child elements of the root.repr will appear later in the PreorderTraversal.
`ensures forall k :: 0 <= k < |PreorderTraversal(root)| ==> forall child :: child in PreorderTraversal(root)[k].repr && child != PreorderTraversal(root)[k] ==> exists j :: k < j < |PreorderTraversal(root)| && PreorderTraversal(root)[j] == child`

```
function PreorderTraversal(root: TreeNode): seq<TreeNode>
    reads root.repr
    requires root.Valid()
    ensures forall x :: x in root.repr ==> x in PreorderTraversal(root)
    ensures forall k :: 0 <= k < |PreorderTraversal(root)| ==> PreorderTraversal(root)[k] in root.repr && PreorderTraversal(root)[k].Valid()
    // ensures forall k :: 0 <= k < |PreorderTraversal(root)| ==> PreorderTraversal(root)[k] in root.repr
{
   if root.left != null && root.right != null then [root]+PreorderTraversal(root.left)+PreorderTraversal(root.right) else if root.left != null then [root]+PreorderTraversal(root.left) else if root.right != null then [root]+PreorderTraversal(root.right) else [root]
}

lemma {:verify true} PreorderTraversalChildrenAreLater(root: TreeNode)
    requires root.Valid()
    //the following does not verify
    ensures forall x :: x in root.repr ==> exists k: nat :: 0 <= k < |PreorderTraversal(root)| && PreorderTraversal(root)[k] == x
{
    // var what := PreorderTraversal(root);
    assert forall x :: x in root.repr ==> x in PreorderTraversal(root);
    forall x | x in root.repr 
        ensures exists k: nat :: 0 <= k < |PreorderTraversal(root)| && PreorderTraversal(root)[k] == x
    {
        assert x in PreorderTraversal(root);
        seqbusiness(PreorderTraversal(root), x);
    }
    // but it verifies here, at least I get the green checkmark
    assert forall x :: x in root.repr ==> exists k: nat :: 0 <= k < |PreorderTraversal(root)| && PreorderTraversal(root)[k] == x;
}

lemma seqbusiness<A>(s: seq<A>, elem: A)
    requires elem in s
    ensures exists k:nat :: 0 <= k < |s| && s[k] == elem
{

}
```

```
class TreeNode {
    var val: int;
    var left: TreeNode?;
    var right: TreeNode?;
    ghost var repr: set<TreeNode>;

    constructor(val: int, left: TreeNode?, right: TreeNode?)
        requires left != null ==> left.Valid()
        requires right != null ==> right.Valid()
        requires left != null && right != null ==> left.repr !! right.repr
        ensures this.val == val
        ensures this.left == left
        ensures this.right == right
        ensures left != null ==> this !in left.repr
        ensures right != null ==> this !in right.repr
        ensures Valid()
    {
        this.val := val;
        this.left := left;
        this.right := right;
        var leftRepr := if left != null then {left}+left.repr else {};
        var rightRepr := if right != null then {right}+right.repr else {};
        this.repr := {this} + leftRepr + rightRepr;
    }

    predicate Valid()
        reads this, repr
        decreases repr
    {
        this in repr &&
        (this.left != null ==>
        (this.left in repr
        && this !in this.left.repr
        && this.left.repr < repr
        && this.left.Valid()
        ))
        && (this.right != null ==>
        (this.right in repr
        && this !in this.right.repr
        && this.right.repr < repr
        && this.right.Valid())) &&
        (this.left != null && this.right != null ==> this.left.repr !! this.right.repr && this.repr == {this} + this.left.repr + this.right.repr)
        && (this.left != null && this.right == null ==> this.repr == {this} + this.left.repr)
        && (this.right != null && this.left == null ==> this.repr == {this} + this.right.repr)
        && (this.right == null && this.left == null ==> this.repr == {this})
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get this to validate by adding `&& x in PreorderTraversal(root)` to the premise of the forall.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it doesn't verify as is and its not clear why.  However, I did manage to get it to go through by lifting out a predicate as follows:

```dafny
predicate WithinRootPreorder(root:TreeNode, x: TreeNode)
reads root.repr
requires root.Valid()
requires x in root.repr {
    exists k: nat :: 0 <= k < |PreorderTraversal(root)| && PreorderTraversal(root)[k] == x
}

lemma {:verify true} PreorderTraversalChildrenAreLater(root: TreeNode)
    //reads root.repr
    requires root.Valid()
    ensures root.repr == old(root.repr)
    //the following does not verify
    ensures forall x :: x in root.repr ==> WithinRootPreorder(root,x)
{
   ...
   assert forall x :: x in root.repr ==> WithinRootPreorder(root,x);
}
```

That seemed to work for me.